# How can I skip the Welcome screen after installing OS X?

Tags: macos, install

How can I skip the Welcome Video/Music that comes up after a fresh install of OS X? I believe you could skip this in Windows by hitting <kbd>ESC</kbd>, but I cannot find a key that has that same effect in OS X.

Comment: The Esc key is OS X is exactly in the same place it would be on Windows, right above backtick/tilde.

Comment: @NReilingh: I think he meant "a key with the same effect".

Comment: yes, i just meant the ESC key has no effect.

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately you can not skip the opening movie - but you can skip the registration process which shows up later by pressing <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd>. When the Setup process is complete the file `.AppleSetupDone` shows up in `/var/db`. (If this file exists it will skip the Setup process altogether)

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>. It’s a Quicktime movie after all.

Comment: no, it does not work.